# setState is not updating after clicking on image

Tags: reactjs

I'm using setstate() two times in my code. at first the method executes when clicking on an image. After updating the state, I'm calling another method in that I'm using updated state to set the state of other element. 
In the first click the code works properly. When i click the image again it is not working.

```
import Heart from '../../assets/images/heart.png';
import yelloHeart from '../../assets/images/yello_heart.png';
```

```
 state = {
        heartImage: Heart,
        heartClicked: false
    }
```

```
 imageClickedHandler = () => {
        this.setState(state => ({ heartClicked: !state.heartClicked }));
        this.changeImage();

    }
```

```
 changeImage = () => {
        if (this.state.heartClicked) {
            this.setState({ heartImage: yelloHeart })
        }
    }
```

```
  <img onClick={this.imageClickedHandler} src={this.state.heartImage} alt="heart" />
```

on second click I'm getting proper output. But I want the image to toggle every time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use one state for this feature.

```js
function App() {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>setState example</h1>
      <img
        style={{
          height: 200,
          width: 200
        }}
        onClick={() => setClicked(clicked => !clicked)}
        src={clicked ? redHeart : heart}
        alt="heart"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can check in codesandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-worker-00v2b?fontsize=14

Answer (score 3):

This is a common pitfall you are encountering. From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
>   right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use
>   componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater,
>   callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update
>   has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous
>   state, read about the updater argument below.

So one thing you could do is:

```
imageClickedHandler = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({
        heartClicked: !state.heartClicked
    }), () => { //  We used callback based version, the callback will fire once the state is set.
        this.changeImage() 
    });

}
```